# Ionic 5 Stripe checkout success_url

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, redirect, stripe-payments, checkout

I am deploying on IOS and Android mobiles a hybrid app developed using ionicframework. How to declare to Stripe Checkout a successUrl referencing a page hosted into the app in the phone? If someone has a working example, i will appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a [DeepLink](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/deeplinks) in your Ionic application and set it as the `success_url` for the Checkout session. So that upon Checkout session completion, Stripe will invoke this DeepLink and navigate your customer to the desired page.